# XML structure while creating from MySQL query in PHP

Tags: php

I have 2 columns in a table im trying to pull rows out of. Im building an xml file and can't get the structure right with my requirements.

Here is what i have working

```
<?php

if (!empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'])) {
    $user = $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'];
} else {
    $user = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
}

//database configuration
$config['mysql_host'] = "localhost";
$config['mysql_user'] = "*****";
$config['mysql_pass'] = "*****";
$config['db_name']    = "*****";
$config['table_name'] = "user";

//connect to host
mysql_connect($config['mysql_host'],$config['mysql_user'],$config['mysql_pass']);
//select database
@mysql_select_db($config['db_name']) or die( "Unable to select database");

$xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
$xml .= "<resources>";
$xml .= "\r\n";

//select all items in table
$sql = "SELECT activity_full FROM user where user = '$user'";
$sqlname = "SELECT name FROM user where user = '$user'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

$resultname = mysql_query($sqlname);
if (!$resultname) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){

    while($result_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

        foreach($result_array as $key => $value){

            $xml .= "<item component=\"ComponentInfo{";

            $xml .= "$value";

            $xml .= "}\" drawable=\"";

            $result_array_name = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultname);
                foreach($result_array_name as $key => $valuename){

                    $xml .= "$valuename";

            }

            $xml .= "\" />";
            $xml .= "\r\n";
            $xml .= "\r\n";
        }
    }
}

$xml .= "</resources>";

//send the xml header to the browser
header ("Content-Type:text/xml");

//output the XML data
echo $xml;



file_put_contents("export/".$user."_appfilter.xml", $xml);

?>
```

That produces this

```
<item component="ComponentInfo{com.apps.aaa.roadside/com.apps.aaa.roadside.Splash}" drawable="aaa_roadside1" />

<item component="ComponentInfo{com.aaa.android.triptik/com.aaa.android.triptik.Bootstrap}" drawable="aaa_triptik" />

<item component="ComponentInfo{au.com.phil.abduction2.demo/au.com.phil.abduction2.demo.menus.PsymIntro}" drawable="abduction" />

<item component="ComponentInfo{au.com.phil.abduction2/au.com.phil.abduction2.menus.PsymIntro}" drawable="abduction" />

<item component="ComponentInfo{au.com.phil/au.com.phil.Intro}" drawable="abduction" />
```

What i need is to apply a header and group items with the same name. Like this

```
<!-- aaa_roadside1 -->
<item component="ComponentInfo{com.apps.aaa.roadside/com.apps.aaa.roadside.Splash}" drawable="aaa_roadside1" />

<!-- aaa_triptik -->
<item component="ComponentInfo{com.aaa.android.triptik/com.aaa.android.triptik.Bootstrap}" drawable="aaa_triptik" />

<!-- abduction -->
<item component="ComponentInfo{au.com.phil.abduction2.demo/au.com.phil.abduction2.demo.menus.PsymIntro}" drawable="abduction" />
<item component="ComponentInfo{au.com.phil.abduction2/au.com.phil.abduction2.menus.PsymIntro}" drawable="abduction" />
<item component="ComponentInfo{au.com.phil/au.com.phil.Intro}" drawable="abduction" />
```

Comment: And what exactly is the logic that dictates what the text of the header should be?

Comment: the name. I added query to the question. When name appears more than once the activity should be duplicated under

Comment: You still seem to be omitting relevant code here. Could you please post the actual code that you're running? Where are `$result` and `$resultname` defined? It looks like the name (the value that you are giving to the `drawable` attribute) can actually be a concatenation of multiple names. How do you want to handle that case?

Comment: i apologize. i have updated

Comment: Also, yes the name that is used for drawable is same that is used for header tag needed.

Comment: I'm sorry, but there is no way that that code produces the output that you say it does.

Comment: i have updated with entire php code. That does produce the xml in the first example above.

Comment: What you want to implement is called a “control break” – basically, for each item/row you output, you compare the relevant criterion of the current row to that of the previous one – and decide what to do based on whether they are the same or different.

Comment: Both of your queries will return the same rows, correct? Just different values from those rows (why you're not just selecting both values in one query is beyond me). Since you have nested `foreach` loops, this means that for each row from `$result_array`, you are iterating through all of the `$result_array_name` rows and appending the value to `$xml`. That's why I don't think the code matches the output.

Comment: I originally had them in one query, Im just trying to figure out how to do this. I exported after you originally questioned and is definitely producing the correct results. Is it not easy to just recommend the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's the solution](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/637684fa9ce409b398d0210a67b970460fd9f9f8) without all the MySQL stuff.

I've translated it as best I could into your existing code, resulting in the below.  It *should* work as-is, but since I'm not connecting to your db, I can't say with absolute certainty.

That being said, you really, *really* need to stop using the `mysql_*` functions and start using either [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysql](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). And use bound parameters in your queries instead of doing interpolation.

```
<?php

if (!empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'])) {
    $user = $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'];
} else {
    $user = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
}

//database configuration
$config['mysql_host'] = "localhost";
$config['mysql_user'] = "*****";
$config['mysql_pass'] = "*****";
$config['db_name']    = "*****";
$config['table_name'] = "user";

//connect to host
mysql_connect($config['mysql_host'],$config['mysql_user'],$config['mysql_pass']);
//select database
@mysql_select_db($config['db_name']) or die( "Unable to select database");

$xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
$xml .= "<resources>";
$xml .= "\r\n";

//select all items in table
// get both columns in just one query
$sql = "SELECT activity_full, name FROM user where user = '$user'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

        if(!isset($previousRow) || !isset($previousRow["name"]) || $previousRow["name"] != $row["name"])
        {
            $xml .= "<!-- " . $row['name'] . " -->\r\n";
        }
        $xml .= "<item component=\"ComponentInfo{";

        $xml .= $row["activity_full"];

        $xml .= "}\" drawable=\"";

        $xml .= $row["name"];

        $xml .= "\" />";
        $xml .= "\r\n";
        $xml .= "\r\n";

        $previousRow = $row;
    }
}

$xml .= "</resources>";

//send the xml header to the browser
header ("Content-Type:text/xml");

//output the XML data
echo $xml;

file_put_contents("export/".$user."_appfilter.xml", $xml);

?>
```

Comment: exactly what i needed. Thank you so much. Im sorry i wasn't more clear on my question but you nailed it