# XML structure while creating from MySQL query in PHP (another one)

Tags: php, xml

I recently asked this question, 
[XML structure while creating from MySQL query in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25513808/xml-structure-while-creating-from-mysql-query-in-php/). I got the answer I needed but now I have a similar case that is missing just one thing.

I duplicated the code and changed as needed but the category rows are not working.

Here is my code

```
$xml2 = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
$xml2 .= "\r\n";
$xml2 .= "<resources>";
$xml2 .= "<version>1</version>";
$xml2 .= "\r\n";

//select all items in table
$sql2 = "SELECT distinct category, name FROM user where user = '$user' and category is not null order by category";

$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
if (!$result2) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

if(mysql_num_rows($result2)>0){

    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)){

        if(!isset($previousRow2) || !isset($previousRow2["category"]) || $previousRow2["category"] != $row2["category"])
        {
            $xml2 .= "\r\n";
            $xml2 .= "<category title=\"" . $row["category"] . "\" />\r\n";
        }
        $xml2 .= "<item drawable=\"";

        $xml2 .= $row2["name"];

        $xml2 .= "\" />";
        $xml2 .= "\r\n";


        $previousRow2 = $row2;
    }
}

$xml2 .= "</resources>";
```

This is outputting this

```
<category title="" />
<item drawable="bigdx_clean" />

<category title="" />
<item drawable="bluetooth" />
<item drawable="bluetooth_audio" />
<item drawable="browser" />
<item drawable="calculator" />
<item drawable="calendar" />
<item drawable="call_history" />
<item drawable="camera" />
```

The titles are blank though.

I'm using the same concept of the working code from other question. It's a different query so I must have something wrong with it?

```
  $xml2 .= "<category title=\"" . $row["category"] . "\" />\r\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing `$row["category"]`, but this variable is not defined anywhere. Did you mean `$row2`?

For what it's worth, `$row2` isn't a very descriptive name for a variable. If you are looking for another variable name because `$row` is taken, perhaps you need to move this into another function, where `$row` will just be local?

If you are (inadvertently) accessing variables that do not exist, it is likely that your on-screen errors are disabled in your local PHP configuration. It is a good idea to turn these on to aid your development process - you'll find that setting in your `php.ini` configuration.

Comment: Thanks. i hate when i overlook these things

Comment: No probs. If you make the configuration change I suggest, you won't miss this in the future `:)`.