# require_once has to be called for a php script to work outside of CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a php file that creates 2 xml files based on a mysql query. Here is the question that shows that php file

[XML structure while creating from MySQL query in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25513808/xml-structure-while-creating-from-mysql-query-in-php)

I have a codeigniter site setup with this structure

```
root
-home
--application
--assets
---php
--system
--user
```

I have this php in assets/php

When i call that php from a hyperlink in my view it won't do anything. no error message or anything.

If i place this in my controller or view it of course runs at page load and works

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/appfilter/home/assets/php/test.php');
```

Why in the world would this be happening?

I would rather not run this every time my page loads. Just when the link is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if u are using Codeigniter for require another file from controller or views try like this

```
require_once(BASEPATH.'/assets/php/test.php');
```